# Error trying to set up WCF service over https

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, web

I am trying to set up a WCF service over https. However I keep getting the error: *"Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."*

Here is the content of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="SoftwareMyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://........./" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedHttp" contract="SoftwareMyService.IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamedHttp" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that this shuold at least have a MyService.svc value.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="StreamedHttp" contract="SoftwareMyService.IMyService" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed this in the end - it's weird because it worked from http without any MyService.svc value, but didn't from https. When I put the full url of my service in the address field it worked. Thanks again +1